# How to return a value from form by concatenating with a string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form as shown below, I need to return the value by concatenating it with another string if that value exists. I'm using semantic-UI React components.

```html
 <Form.Group widths="equal">
        <Form.Select
          fluid
          id="reqHed"
          label="Request Header"
          placeholder="Select the Header"
          name="reqHeader"
          options={config.header}
          onChange={(e, { value }) => {
            setreqHeader(value);
          }}
        />
        <Form.Input
          fluid
          id="headerKey"
          label="Name"
          placeholder="Name"
          onChange={(event) => setHeaderKey(event.target.value)}
        />
        <Form.Input
          fluid
          id="headerValue"
          label="Value"
          placeholder="Value"
          onChange={(event) => setHeaderValue(event.target.value)}
        />
      </Form.Group>
```

While OnClick of this form, I have stored these values to the state variables (in my case reqHeader,headerKey, and headerValue) and added them to the payload for a POST operation.

```js
const saveHandler = async () => {
    return await axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: config.App_URL.createMock,
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      data: model,
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(`Error while creating mock => ${error}`);
    });
  };
```

I tried by doing a null check as shown below. When I do this way, reqHeader is missing from the payload upon sending the request.

I'm setting the state with React Hooks:

```js
const [reqHeader, setreqHeader] = useState("");
const [headerKey, setHeaderKey] = useState("");
const [headerValue, setHeaderValue] = useState("");
```

My payload is as follows

```js
let model = {
    emailId: email,
    Manager: [
      {
        appName: app,
        heirarchy: "child", 
        reqHeader: () => {
          return reqHeader
            ? reqHeader + ":" + headerKey + "=" + headerValue
            : "";
        },
        url: url,
      },
    ],
  };
```

How can I properly check the value, if the value is null return an empty string else perform a concat operation as I mentioned in the payload?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. What do you mean by "fetching these values"?

Comment: @goto1 I'm storing values from the field to state variables such as reqHeader, headerKey and headerValue. And then I need to do a check if the reqHeader is present or not.

Comment: So what is the problem you're having?

Comment: Then the value is assigned to the model. Is this the right way to implement ?

Comment: If you're asking whether this is how you'd do string concatenation in `JavaScript`, yeah that's fine. If you're asking for something else that is specific to what you're doing, I am not really sure what your requirements are so it's impossible to say.

Comment: @goto1: When I do this way, reqHeader is missing from the payload upon sending the request

Comment: Then your check is probably incorrect. I can't tell what your initial value for `reqHeader` is from the code that you provided or what the `setHeaderKey` is doing. And also, I don't know how you're actually using `Model` in that `POST` request you're mentioning.

Comment: the initial value is null and setHeaderKey sets the new value from the form. By using axios I'm doing the post operation

Comment: can you include the component state too

Comment: Yes. Please check the question again

Comment: Like you are not correctly handling the select changes.
this is what you have
`
   onChange={(e, { value }) => {
       setreqHeader(value);
   }}
`
should be
`
   onChange={({ target: { value }  }) => {
       setreqHeader(value);
   }}
`

Comment: was that the problem?

Comment: @akolliy: No, I'll add your suggestions accordingly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219903/discussion-between-akolliy-and-akhil-suseelan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select changes is incorrectly handled. So your condition to set reqHeader will alway be null.

Here's what I captured in your code, In the select Component

```
// this is wrong, value is undefined
onChange={(e, { value }) => {
   setreqHeader(value);
}}
```

Correct way is to replace event with an object, then destructure target, and value from target.

```
/*
1. refactor select field handle change. 
2. refactor reqHeader in your model from function to string. 
*/
// correct
onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
   setreqHeader(value);
}}

const saveHandler = async () => {
  const model = {
    emailId: email,
    Manager: [{
      appName: app,
      heirarchy: 'child',
      reqHeader: reqHeader ? reqHeader + ':' + headerKey + '=' + headerValue : '',
      url: url
    }]
  }

  return axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: config.App_URL.createMock,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: model
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(`Error while creating mock => ${error}`)
  })
}
```